# JavaScript remain to open popup in code behind (asp.net C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Pass value from Grid View to another page and I would like to remain to show my popup. but It's close pop up when I click button on GidView 
How do I solve my java script? Thank you

Here my code:

```js
open: function (action, value) {
  var topWindow = this.getTopWindow();
  if (topWindow != window) {
    topWindow.$.FsPopup.open(action, value);
    return;
  }


  if (this.top == 0) return;
  var repoItem = this.repository[--this.top];

  repoItem.windoo.modal = false;
  repoItem.windoo.dialog("open");
  repoItem.windoo.dialog("destroy")
  repoItem.windoo.remove();

  var func = repoItem.callback;
  if (func)
    func(action, value);
},
```

```
protected void grd_Employee_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "SelectEmployee")
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow grdRow = grd_Employee.Rows[rowIndex];
                HiddenField obj_hdEmpCode = grdRow.FindControl("hdEmpID") as HiddenField;
                int empID = Convert.ToInt32(obj_hdEmpCode.Value.ToString().Trim());
                this.OpenPopup(empID);
            }
        }
```

```
public void OpenPopup(object ObjectReturn)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), string.Format("$.FsPopup.open('ok', '{0}'); void(0);", ReturnKey), true);
    }
```

Comment: you haven't asked us a question or mentioned any problem you'd like help with. A simple statement of what you've done doesn't tell us what you want from us.

Comment: @ADyson Dear sir, Sorry I've already edited my question

Comment: Thanks. Is this "popup" a real browser-window popup, or just an effect generated by some JavaScript and CSS? From the code it looks like the latter, but it would help to confirm it. Based on that assumption, I would assume it closes the pop-up because your page is refreshing and doing a full postback. Therefore anything which was done on the client-side is destroyed. However it looks like your "OpenPopup" C# method adds a script block which tries to re-open the popup when the page is re-loaded...is that not working?

Comment: Because when you click some link or button in grid view and this command grd_Employee_RowCommand is executed. This makes a postback and so when the page refresh, the popup will disappear. You need to write the logic inside grd_Employee_RowCommand into a web method and make an ajax call to pass data from grid view to other page.

Comment: this popup is generated by asp.net C#, CSS , it's like web form. And I try to edit my Java Script  but it is still not working.

Comment: so your grid is in popup and you are clicking a button in grid and it pass data to another page. on clicking button, the popup wit grid closes, but you dont want it to close. is that right?

Comment: @Chidambaram yes, that's right. Thank you very much for your idea I will try it.